# how to calculate the steady state mc linear equations

Tags: markov-chains, steady-state

i have the following Markov chains equations and not sure how to solve those:
***a=.2 a +.5b+0.6d
b=.1a+.1b+.2d
c=0.7a+.1c
d=.4b+.9c+.2d
pi=a+b+c+d***
how do you approach that? i tried
***-.8a+.5b+.6d=0***
but that just gave me zeros for everything. the teacher did not show me how to resolve those and i m not sure how to approach ..

Answer (score -1):

You need to remove the singularity by removing one of the linearly dependent equations and use instead the probability condition: $a +  b + c + d = 1$.